# FLIP Fluids - How to include foam & bubbles when exporting the geometry?

Tags: fluid-simulation, external-applications

I am using the FLIP Fluid add-on to generate a water simulation. I managed to export the animation into .obj sequence but here is the problem now.

The **Foam & Bubbles** particles generated from FLIP Fluid are not included after exporting the animation into .obj sequence. Only the main fluid got exported.

**Q:** How to include foam & bubbles during the .obj sequence export?

Comment: You may want to try exporting to the Alembic (.abc) format which is a popular choice for exporting simulation data. But beware that if exporting to other 3D software, they might not recognize or be compatible with the structure of Blender's Alembic meshes. More information here: https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Alembic-Export-Support

Answer (score 0):

When exporting as Alembic, there is a checkbox to *include particles* or *include hair*.  I use .abc files to import the deformable mesh into Keyshot and the particles will import as well.

The only problem is that all the particles (even ones that should not be born yet) will come into Keyshot all on Frame 1.  There are also Python scripts out there that will write an "instance" of each particle to keyframes. I believe those will allow .obj sequence export.  I haven't had much luck, only because I know nothing about Python scripting.